# obtener max valor en una fecha

Tags: sql, sql-server

No me trae el maximo valor de la fecha de cada registro, me repite el mimo valor de serie en algunos rows, le coloque el max en la fecha pero sigue trayendo dos rows , esta es mi query

```html
SELECT A.Mac AS SERIE2,D.DESCRIPCION AS TIPO_MOVIMIENTO,MAX(B.Fecha_Activacion) AS FECHA_ACTIVACION 
FROM CableMo A  
LEFT JOIN Clientes B ON A.Clv_CableMo = B.Clv_CableMo 
LEFT JOIN IAPA C ON A.Clv_CableMo = C.Clv_Aparato  
LEFT JOIN Trab D ON C.Trabajo = D.TRABAJO 
where a.Mac in('80554290967')
AND C.Clv_Or = (
SELECT MAX(Clv_Or) FROM IAPA
WHERE Clv_Aparato = A.Clv_CableMo)
GROUP BY A.Mac,D.DESCRIPCION ,B.Fecha_Activacion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás agrupando por Fecha de Activación. Solo necesitas quitarla del `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT A.MacCableMo AS SERIE2,D.DESCRIPCION AS TIPO_MOVIMIENTO,MAX(B.Fecha_Activacion) AS FECHA_ACTIVACION 
FROM CatCableMo A  
LEFT JOIN ClientesDig B ON A.Clv_CableMo = B.Clv_CableMo 
LEFT JOIN IAPARATOS C ON A.Clv_CableMo = C.Clv_Aparato  
LEFT JOIN Trabajos D ON C.Trabajo = D.TRABAJO 
where a.MacCableModem in('80554290967','L-110411','L-78264','L-57270')
AND C.Clv_Orden = (
SELECT MAX(Clv_Orden) FROM IAPARATOS 
WHERE Clv_Aparato = A.Clv_CableMo)
GROUP BY A.MacCableMo ,D.DESCRIPCION ;
```

Comment: gracias es que también agrupa el valor de B.Fecha_Activacion y solo son 2 campos A.MacCableMo ,D.DESCRIPCION

Comment: Estás agrupando la columna Fecha_Activacion por las columnas A.MacCableMo y D.DESCRIPCION